# Riddance vs Freedom

Tags: differences

Riddance translate as the "Freedom action" in Portuguese. What's their difference in english?

From dictionary.com:
Riddance: the act or fact of clearing away or out, as anything undesirable.
Freedom: the state of being free or at liberty.

Looks like Riddance is just "stronger", is there any pratical difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get rid of something, you are free from it. But in general the two have very different connotations. I get rid of my garbage and good riddance!), but the word *freedom* brings to mind the idea that I am living in a free country, that I am not a slave, and things like that.

Except in a handful of very specific situations, the two are somehow linked:

> I finally dumped my bossy girlfriend - good riddance! I'm finally free!

But *riddance* is related to the act of *removing* something, whereas the word *freedom* is related to a situation of *being* free; those are quite different concepts.

As *Anonym* remarks, *riddance* his usually associated with (removal) of something *negative*, whereas *freedom* has overwhelmingly *positive* connotations.

Comment: I'd say that *riddance* concentrates on the removal of something bad whereas *freedom* concentrates on the attainment of a better state.

Comment: @Anonym A good point, I will add that positive/negative as well :)

Comment: It should be noted that riddance is mainly used in the expression "good riddance," which expresses relief that you are now free of something--a bad boy/girlfriend, for example--that you are better off without.